# javascript function app validation issue

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I am having a trouble with a function I have made. A company I am building a website for needed a sizer app built so customers could enter measurements and see what size model they need to buy. I have built the sizer app and it works fine, but I am having trouble with validation. I am trying to accomplish two things:

1. I need to make sure all three fields have a value entered, so if a field is left blank then an error message needs to be displayed and the function will stop.
2. I need to make sure all the data entered are numbers greater than zero and if not then an error message is displayed and the function will stop.

I am a beginner to JS so please excuse me if I am not even close, but I feel like I am right there. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The code is below

HTML

```
    <div class="box">

        <h2>Calculate Your TRiCC Size</h2>

        <noscript><p>This Widget requires Javascript</p></noscript>

        <!-- FORM -->


        <form id='TriccSizerForm' method='post'>



            <!-- Height -->

            <label for='triccHeight'>Height in inches:</label>

            <input id='triccHeight' type='number' name='triccHeight' value="" required>



            <!-- Width -->


            <label for='triccWidth'>Width in inches:</label>

            <input id='triccWidth' type='number' name='triccWidth' value="" required>



            <!-- Depth -->


            <label for='triccDepth'>Depth in inches:</label>

            <input id='triccDepth' type='number' name='triccDepth' value="" required>




            <div id="mistake"> </div>

            <div id="error"> </div>



            <!-- Answer -->


            <div id="triccAns"> </div>


            <!-- Submit button -->


            <button type='submit' value='Calculate' onclick='triccSizer(); return false;'>Calculate</button>

        </form>
```

JS

```
function triccSizer() {





// Perform script



var h = document.getElementById("triccHeight");

var w = document.getElementById("triccWidth");

var d = document.getElementById("triccDepth");

var errors = false;


// validate

if (w.value === "") {

    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the width';

} else if (d.value === "") {

    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the depth';

} else if (h.value === "") {

    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the height';
} else {

    errors = false;
}



if (isNaN(w.value)) {

    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the width';

} else if (isNaN(d.value)) {

    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the depth';

} else if (isNaN(h.value)) {

    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the height';

} else {

    errors = false;
} 


// Get Model


if (errors == true) {

    document.getElementById("mistake").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you entered something inccorect into the form. Please try again.';

} else { 


    if ((w.value < 34) && (d.value < 35) && (h.value < 35)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 36A'; 

    else if ((w.value < 54) && (d.value < 35) && (h.value < 35)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 3656A Standard';

    else if ((w.value < 34) && (d.value < 54) && (h.value < 35)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 3656A Deep';

    else if ((w.value < 34) && (d.value < 35) && (h.value < 55)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 3656A Upright';

    else if ((w.value < 69) && (d.value < 35) && (h.value < 35)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 36A Extended';

    else if ((w.value < 89) && (d.value < 35) && (h.value < 35)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 3656A Short Extended';

    else if ((w.value < 109) && (d.value < 35) && (h.value < 35)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 3656A Extended';          

    else if ((w.value < 44) && (d.value < 45) && (h.value < 45)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 46A';

    else if ((w.value < 89) && (d.value < 45) && (h.value < 45)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 46A Extended';

    else if ((w.value < 54) && (d.value < 55) && (h.value < 55)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 56A';

    else if ((w.value < 109) && (d.value < 55) && (h.value < 55)) 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Choose Model 56A Extended (You Must Contact Us For This Model and Pricing)';                   

    else 
        document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'You need a customized TRiCC Protective Cover. Please call 224-698-7422 for assistance.';

    }
```

}

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/zwNn4/ What specific problems are you having?

Comment: If I leave an input blank it will give an error message and an answer. Instead I want to have the error message display without an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "else" blocks are causing a problem, so better yet, eliminate them. :)

```
document.getElementById("mistake").innerHTML = ''; // empty previous error
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = ''; 

// validate non blank
if (w.value === "") {
    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the width';

} else if (d.value === "") {
    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the depth';

} else if (h.value === "") {
    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the height';
}


// validate non zero
if (isNaN(w.value)) {
    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the width';

} else if (isNaN(d.value)) {
    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the depth';

} else if (isNaN(h.value)) {
    errors = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Sorry but you must enter a valid number greater than zero for the height';
```

What is happening in your code is that you get an error flag when checking for blank, but that error get cleared when checking separately for non zero, which does not match any "if" conditions and executes the `} else { errors = false; }` block.

Comment: I took your advice and used the below code. It seems to be working but I still have one problem. If I type text into one of the input field the error message that displays as the error message for a blank input.

Comment: if ((w.value === "") || (d.value === "") || (h.value === "")) {
  document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Sorry, but you left a field blank. Please fill out all fields and then hit submit';
 }else ((isNaN(w.value)) || (isNaN(d.value)) || (isNaN(h.value))) {
  document.getElementById("triccAns").innerHTML = 'Sorry, but you need to enter a valid number in the fields above';
 }

Comment: Oh, ya. Okay, so I removed the "else" blocks that set errors back to false. You don't need them since you set errors to false right off the bat. Response updated. Nice call.

Answer (score 0):

if you use onclick event over the button, the event will be lauched before the form submition, why don't use onsubmit form event instead the onclick event?

and in number inputs you now can use min and max attributes

Comment: when i use onsubmit how would i need to change the js? I tried onsubmit and it clears out the inputs and doesn't output the response

Comment: you need to put <form onsubmit="triccSizer()"> and put return false when an error was received, or return true when all it's ok, also delete the onclick event in the button. If you want to use your script for only html5 browsers it's enought writing the required, max and min attributes, be sure that you are using <!DOCTYPE html>  and the <meta charset="utf-8" /> tags in your html document

Comment: @CharC Do you want to submit the form at all? Or is this only used in the browser to display the proper Model according to measurements.

Comment: when they enter their measurements it will kick back an answer so they can see which model they need. Then they can select the model in the drop down and buy.If I only use onclick and not onsubmit then do I need to worry about validation?

Comment: Since you're not submitting the form I think using the onclick event on the button is just fine. Regarding validation, that's not only for data integrity but to assist the user, so ya I think validation is necessary.